# Запись данных в xlsx с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго времени суток.
Можно ли как-то записать в xlsx файл переменные из JS.
к примеру 
var rezult = 123;
И как-то записать ее в xlsx файл, например в ячейку A2.

Comment: Опиши вопрос поподробнее...  Где этот файл? В компе или на сайте...? Практический не покажу, но теоретический , это можно осуществить на NodeJS...  Если файл на сайте, то серверный NodeJS? Если на компе, то уже приложение десктопное на NodeJS...

Comment: Пока файл на сайте, но в последствие его надо будет загружать на сервер. Как я понял надо копать в направлении NodeJS. Если не сложно можете дать ссылку на материалы посвященные NodeJS. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Тут вопрос главный, как именно на `JS` захватить ячейку ту или иную...

Comment: Я сам еще в `nodejs ` новичок, я пользуюсь этим сайтом https://nodeguide.ru/doc/

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860728/reading-excel-file-using-node-js там список библиотек js для работы с xlsx файлами. И вот еще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859901/parse-xlsx-with-node-and-create-json/40292005#40292005